# Google Cloud VPN prerequisite

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'd like to use the Google Cloud VPN to establish connectivity between three office networks in different geographical locations. I'd like to be sure of a few things:

1. Do I need a static IP or not?
2. Do I need any special physical devices on premises i.e. router, firewall?
3. In all three locations I have simple routers which are wireless/wired, so what kind of configs I will have to make to connect it to Google Cloud Platform as on-premise networks have Internet connectivity with dynamic public addresses which change, or can change. What will be the on-premise VPN gateway?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud VPN product is used to establish a tunnel between your premise and the Google Cloud platform.

If you want to established betweens your offices, you need a VPN gateway and a static IP address on each site. Then you can create the three tunnels (site1/site2, site1/site3, site2/site3).

Another options is to have a central OpenVPN server with client-to-client option enabled. Then you can work with dynamic IP addresses but performances could be impacted.

Answer (score 0):

1.-

In order to create a Cloud VPN tunnel you need a gateway, so a virtual [VPN gateway](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview#terms) running in GCP managed by Google, using a configuration you specify in your project. Each Cloud VPN gateway is a regional resource using a regional external IP address.

2.-

There are no special devices, however there are specific [ciphers supported](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers) by GCP according to the IKE version.

Additionally, there is a list of [interoperability guides](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/interop-guides) for some vendors that can help you.

3.-

At the beginning you need to create three tunnels, however it depends on your needs and the topology you want to have. Thus, please take a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/router/docs/concepts/overview#example_topologies) which has some examples of VPN topologies. Additionally, this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-on-premises-gateway) can help you to configure your VPN on-premise gateway.